# To find the real conjugate (Maple Procedure)

Tags: algorithms, maple

I'm trying to write a procedure which returns the real conjugate of a real number.

Ex: $2 + \sqrt3 \rightarrow 2 - \sqrt3$

I tried:

```
rconj:= proc(x) local i,y; y:=-x; for i to nops(x) do if type(op(i,x),rational) then op(i,y):= -op(i,x); end if; end do; return y; end proc
```

It isn't working. Error statement: "Error, (in rconj) invalid left hand side in assignment".

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simple cases

```
rconj := proc(x::radnum)
  maptype(`+`, (y -> `if`(type(y,anything^fraction), -y, y)), x)
end proc;
```

this will do what you want.  It is not properly general (it really doesn't do the right thing for cube roots), but gives you a starting point.

Comment: Thanks. Though, I almost know nothing of the commands and assignments that you used (I'm a beginner). However, could you tell me why my code did not work? Where did I go wrong?

Comment: @BolzWeir: To answer your question of what was wrong with your code: To change the **i**th operand of **x**, you don't use **op(i,x):=** ...; rather, you use **subsop(i= ..., x)**.